# How can we MOQ UserProperties on a VSTO ContactItem

Tags: c#, vsto, moq, outlook-addin

While using Moq on a VSTO ContactItem, I recieve the following error:

```
variable 'x' of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

The code is below:

```
public class ContactItemTests
{
    private Mock<ContactItem> _contactItemMock;


    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        _contactItemMock = new Mock<ContactItem>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {

        var firstName= _contactItemMock.Setup(x => x.FirstName).Returns("Don");
        var userProperty = _contactItemMock.Setup(x => x.UserProperties.Find("Test",null)).Returns(()=>null);

        Assert.IsTrue(userProperty == null);
    }
}
```

My question is:

Why can't VS 2017 find the UserProperties property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserProperties is another object that requires a setup.